# Sorting files with DirectoryIterator

Tags: php, spl

I'm making a directory listing PHP5 script for lighttpd. In a given directory, I'd like to be able to list direct sub-directories and files (with informations).

After a quick search, [DirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php) seems to be my friend:

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('.') as $file)
{
    echo $file->getFilename() . '<br />';
}
```

but I'd like to be able to sort files by filename, date, mime-types...etc

How to do this (with ArrayObject/ArrayIterator?) ?

Thanks

Comment: excellent question, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Above solution didn't work for me. Here's what I suggest:

```
class SortableDirectoryIterator implements IteratorAggregate
{

    private $_storage;

    public function __construct($path)
    {
    $this->_storage = new ArrayObject();

    $files = new DirectoryIterator($path);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $this->_storage->offsetSet($file->getFilename(), $file->getFileInfo());
    }
    $this->_storage->uksort(
        function ($a, $b) {
            return strcmp($a, $b);
        }
    );
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
    return $this->_storage->getIterator();
    }

}
```

Comment: Using this `SortableDirectoryIterator` instead of `DirectoryIterator` magically works for me. However some explanation of what it actually does would be nice. Does it simplay sort after filename/path?

Answer (score 2):

Philipp W. posted a good example here: http://php.oregonstate.edu/manual/en/directoryiterator.isfile.php

```
function cmpSPLFileInfo( $splFileInfo1, $splFileInfo2 )
{
    return strcmp( $splFileInfo1->getFileName(), $splFileInfo2->getFileName() );
}

class DirList extends RecursiveDirectoryIterator
{
    private $dirArray;

    public function __construct( $p )
    {
        parent::__construct( $p );
        $this->dirArray = new ArrayObject();
        foreach( $this as $item )
        {
            $this->dirArray->append( $item );
        }
        $this->dirArray->uasort( "cmpSPLFileInfo" );
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
        return $this->dirArray->getIterator();
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem I'm finding with this is that it seems to sort everything properly, but the numerical keys remain the same.  This seems to make a foreach iterate in the original order, even though a print_r prints everything in the correct order.

Comment: *foreach* always follows the order of the array, it doesn't sort by numerical keys.

Comment: change the above code from **uasort()** to **usort()** to reset the keys.

Comment: You can't use usort on ArrayObject ( http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php )