# How do you get a directory listing sorted by creation date in PHP?

Tags: php, sorting, scandir

I have to list directories by using scandir() function but result array should be sorted according to date and time of directory created.

Regards
Deepak

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386092/sorting-files-with-directoryiterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try backticks

```
$listOfFiles = `ls -ltr`;
```

and then use explode to get the into an array format

Answer (score 0):

With scandir() you cannot.

Check [this](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/10156.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be solved by using `filemtime($dirPath)` function.

code sample:

```
if (file_exists($dirPath)) {
    echo "last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($dirPath));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get results you need into an array and sort it... I'm not aware of a scandir option that can do this directly.