# Sort images from read(); directory function

Tags: php, sorting

here's my code. But the read(): in the while loop does not seems to sort my result aphabetically. Is there a way to sort my result?
tks
Seby

```
 <?php
 $save_path_folder_images = '../simplegallery/users/'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'       /'.$_REQUEST['gal_folder'].'/thumbs/';
 $save_path_folder_images_full = '/simplegallery/users/'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'/'.$_REQUEST['gal_folder'].'/slides/';
$folder=dir($save_path_folder_images);

$counter = 1;
while($folderEntry=$folder->read())
{
    if($folderEntry!="." && $folderEntry!="..")
    {?>
         <div class="imgs" >
                <div class="thumb" >                        
                        <label for="img<?php echo $counter; ?>"><img class="img" src="<?php echo $save_path_folder_images.$folderEntry; ?>" /></label>                          
                    </div>
                <div class="inner">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="chk " id="img<?php echo $counter; ?>" name="img_name[]" value="<?php echo $save_path_folder_images_full.$folderEntry; ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
    $counter++;
    }
}
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->read()` does not attempt to sort the output, you could loop through `read()` once, pushing the output into an array. Then run it through `natcasesort()` (http://php.net/natcasesort) to sort the array, then print it out.

So two loops.

```
while($folderEntry=$folder->read())
{
  $fileList[]  = $folderEntry;
}
natcasesort($fileList);
foreach($fileList as $folderEntry)
{
  //your printing
}
```

Comment: Hi sir, that's what I don't know how to do from what I have right now. Can you help me a little on it please?

Comment: Yep, totally working sir. thank you very very much for your help. Have a nice day..
Seby

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [DirectoryIterator][1]?

```
$files = array();
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($save_path_folder_images);
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {     
   if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
       $files[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
   }
}

natcasesort($files);
```

check this thread as well [Sorting files with DirectoryIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386092/sorting-files-with-directoryiterator)
[1]: https://www.php.net/directory_iterator